# How can we cast live streaming video to any screen with the help of chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, live-streaming, agora.io

I want to cast my live streaming Agora video to chromecast device. So does the chromecast delegate methods currently support live streaming from a camera device itself or is it limited to only pre-encoded video url?